# Estimating elasticity of substitution in nested CES functions

Tags: elasticity, production-function, elasticity-of-substitution

I have aggregate data on $L_t, K_t$ and $X_t$, and want to estimate elasticity of substitution parameters, $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ for these factors. Assuming the production function takes the following form: $$Y_t=(A_lL^{\gamma}+[A_kK_t^{\sigma} +A_xX_t^{\sigma}]^\frac{\gamma}{\sigma})^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}  $$

Technology parameters, $A$s are not observable and hence need to be controlled for in an econometric specification. I am thinking of first estimating the parameter, $\sigma$, on the inner CES function combining $K$ and $X$. Then I should be able to estimate the outer CES parameter, $\gamma$. In a way, the two parameters are not jointly estimated. Would this method be valid, I mean, in statistical sense? Will I get consistent and unbiased estimates? 
I've read papers on non-linear regression methods, but was wondering if this simple approach is feasible. 
Thanks.

Comment: This is related to the [question](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10586/ces-production-function-estimation) I asked. The linked reference therein estimates a normalized nested CES production function. Might be of interest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CES production function estimation](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10586/ces-production-function-estimation)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate. That linked question is a two input production function and the above is a three input production function that is nested.

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting technology parameters and assuming constant returns to scale, the parameters $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ are jointly estimable via dynamic (least squares) programming.
See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.01052.pdf).

Comment: I cannot ignore the technology parameters. Thanks.